# db.expando + App Engine + Change an integer property value to float value

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore

I've following model set up initially

```
class Obj (db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    rating = db.IntegerProperty(default=0, required=False)
```

There are entities already created with above, such as:

name="test1", rating="3"

So, **I need to change the rating type to float**. I was trying to achieve this with db.Expando

```
class Obj (db.Expando):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    rating = db.FloatProperty(default=0, required=False)
```

Before I'm able to retrieve the instance of the Obj model to update it to float value, I've already got the following error:

> Property rating must be a float

At first, I got this error, because I wasn't using db.Expando. However, after using db.Expando, I assumed this error shouldn't come into place ? Since it can dynamically change value, type etc as I read the articles.

Being new to db.Expando, I need help. Does anyone have clue to what happened ?

**EDIT**

```
for o in Obj.all():
    a = []
    if o.rating:
        o.rating = float(str(restaurant.rating))
    else:
        o.rating = float(0)    
    a.append(restaurant)

db.put(a)
```

After having above code, the same error pops up

> Property rating must be a float

**SOLUTION**
Temporarily removed the rating from model definition and updated the values to float first and then add the new rating definition with db.FloatProperty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `db.Expando` model allows you to add properties that aren't defined in the class itself; however, any properties that *are* explicitly defined in the class do need to be the correct type.

Simply removing `rating` from the model definition may work for you.

Comment: Right, the Expando semantics only apply to properties *not* declared in the class.  When you drop the rating property definition, you will get the value as an int; if you want to turn it into a float, you'll have to change it (e.rating = float(e.rating)) and write the entity back. Possibly use the map/reduce library to do this over the entire datastore.